# Почему в стандартном вызове stl алгоритма происходит передача функтора по значению?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl, лямбда-выражение, функтор

Возник вопрос - почему, в приведенной сигнатуре, предикат передается по значению:(https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type
    count_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

Мейерс в "*Эффективное использование STL*" писал, что такой способ передачи дает две проблемы:

- Расходы при копировании больших объектов
- Отсутствие полиморфизма для объектов, которые мы передали по значению

Эти проблемы решаются тем, что мы создаем оболочку - функтор с указателем на тяжелый объект с виртуальными функциями.

Однако Мейерс не отвечает почему вообще в стандарте в данном месте присутствует передача по значению.

Почему изначально не вшита передача по указателю?

**UPD:** Пример того, что получается передавать через указатель необходимые объекты:

```
namespace ustd   //user std
{

    template <typename InputIt, typename UnaryPredicate> 
    typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type
        count_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate* predicate)
    {
        typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type count = 0;

        while (first != last)
            if ((*predicate)(*first++))
                ++count;
        return count;
    }
};

//проверяем
bool predicate(int i)
{
    return i > 2;
}

class Functor
{
public:
    explicit Functor(int i)
        : i(i)
    {}

    bool operator()(int var) const
    {
        return var > i;
    }
private:
    int i = 0;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3 }; //size = 6

    std::cout << ustd::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), &Functor(2));     //вывод 3
    std::cout << ustd::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), predicate);       //вывод 3
    std::cout << ustd::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), &[](int i)-> bool //вывод 3
    {
        return i > 2;
    });


    return 0;
}
```

**UPD 2 :** Похоже зависит от версии компилятора. Для верхнего примера C++14 (gcc 8.3) кидает справедливую ошибку:

```
error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
  std::cout << ustd::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), &Functor(2));
```

Comment: Передайте, пожалуйста, через указатель лямбда-функцию... Вопрос снимется?

Comment: Спасибо, за комментарий! Пока не понятно почему это должно быть проблемой. Лямбда-функция по факту это тот же самый функтор. Вместо лямбда-выражения подставляется **объект** класса, который мы этим лямбда-выражением описали. Сейчас протестил - вроде все норм. Сейчас в пост выложу пример с кодом

Comment: До уточнения ситуации свой ответ пока приукрыл. Ваш код в VC++ приводит к предупреждению об использовании **нестандартного** расширения - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4238?view=vs-2019 В принципе, логично - вы получаете адрес временного объекта, что, если не ошибаюсь, в стандарте не разрешается.

Comment: *Похоже зависит от версии компилятора.* - это нестандарт, а не версия компилятора.

Comment: На GCC и Clang с `-pedantic-errors` в примере работает только второй вариант. На первый и третий ругаются: `error: taking address of rvalue`. Так что почему не сделали передачу по указателю - понятно. А вот почему forwarding ссылку не поставили...

Comment: Все верно. Согласен, что неправильно брать адрес от rvalue объектов. Видимо, передача по значению нужна для _удобного_ использования лямбда-выражений. Интересен тот факт, что если создать объекты и уже от них взять адрес, то все заработает. Т.е. сначала сохранить лямбду\функтор в переменную, а уже от этой переменной взять адрес.

Comment: Да, но в самой функции формально потребуется разыменование назад... Мейерс, кстати, прямо советует подумать над передачей по значению того, что передается по ссылке (а передача по ссылке по сути ничем не отличается от передачи указателя).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что через указатель вы не сможете передать, например, лямбда-функцию.

Через ссылку - можно, но только константную. Но тогда вы не сможете передать ту же лямбду, которая, например, захватывает что-то по ссылке...

Попробуйте сами - убедитесь, что возможности передачи чего угодно существенно уменьшаются...

Тут - https://ideone.com/11ctGT - я выложил код с передачей через указатель. И две закомментированные лямбды. Поиграйтесь, раскомментируйте и добейтесь, чтоб код скомпилировался...

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type
    Count_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate * p)
{
    typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type ret = 0;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if ((*p)(*first)) {
            ret++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

bool even(int i)
{
    return i%2 == 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};

    int total = 0;
    //cout << Count_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[](int x) { return x%2 == 0; }) << endl;
    //cout << Count_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[&total](int x) { ++total; return x%2 == 0; }) << endl;
    cout << Count_if(v.begin(),v.end(),even) << endl;

}
```

**Update**

Кстати, Мейерс (*Эффективный и современный С++*, раздел 5.5, стр. 190) прямо советует -

> Подход, который часто позволяет добиться производительности без увеличения сложности, заключается в замене передачи параметров по ссылке передачей по значению.

Кстати, логично. Функция и так будет передаваться через указатель, а лямбда или создаваемый функтор только усугубят ситуацию разыменованием, которое не нужно...

Comment: Но можно было бы использовать forwarding ссылку.

Comment: Написал в посте пример передачи лямбды через указатель. Вроде работает. Может я что-то не понимаю...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Чуть подробнее можно?

Comment: @Harry Имею в виду `UnaryPredicate &&p`. https://ideone.com/AfbqbP

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, согласен. Но ситуация принципиально не изменится, нет? Все равно будет создаваться временный объект, только и того, что будет (конечно, если не соптимизирует) немного теряться эффективность на постоянном разыменовании ссылки за сценой, так сказать...

Comment: Угу, наверное дело в производтельности. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357159/why-is-templated-functor-passed-as-value-and-not-forwarding-reference) тоже что-то похожее пишут.

Comment: Дело не только в лямбда-функциях,  а в удобстве в целом.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо вас вводит в заблуждение запись аргумента как `UnaryPredicate p`. Она не означает передачу по значению. Если тип `UnaryPredicate` будет `Functor const &`, то будет передаваться ссылка. Пример ([online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/UteDfV)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

// non copyable, non movable
class
t_Predicate
{
    public: t_Predicate(void) {}
    private: t_Predicate(t_Predicate const & other) = delete;
    private: t_Predicate(t_Predicate && other) = delete;
    private: void operator =(t_Predicate const & other) = delete;
    private: void operator =(t_Predicate & other) = delete;
    public: bool operator ()(int const & value) const { return 0 != (value % 2); }
};

int main()
{
    ::std::vector const values{0, 2, 3, 7, 9, 12};
    t_Predicate const pred{};
    auto const count
    {
        ::std::count_if
        <
            decltype(values)::const_iterator
        ,   t_Predicate const &
        >
        (
            values.begin(), values.end(), pred
        )
    };
    assert(2 == count);
    return 0;
}
```

Работает в msvc, но не работает в gcc. Почему так? Потому что в ненормативной секции стандарта реализациям дается разрешение на копирование предикатов, что и пытается делать библиотека, идущая с gcc. Мне лень искать тикет, но вроде это известный недостаток. Ну а пока для совместимости используйте `reference_wrapper` или его аналоги, как то рекомендуется в стандарте:

> **28.3 Algorithms requirements [algorithms.requirements]**
>   8 [Note: Unless otherwise specified, algorithms that take function objects as arguments are permitted to copy those function objects freely. Programmers for whom object identity is important should consider using a wrapper class that points to a noncopied  implementation object such as reference_wrapper (23.14.5), or some equivalent solution. —end note ]